# React-select facing multiple errors when implementing select all/unselect all with initial loaded values

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to implement a react-select component that has the **Select All** function with initial loaded values from an API.
After I selected the options, it will send the selected options to it's parent component, `App.js` in this case with the method `getEmployeeVisibility`.
The select works if there is no initial loaded values, but when I have some initial values that are loaded to the select, there are a few problems that I'm facing:

1. I have to double click to select an option after the initial click
2. If there's only one initial loaded option , I will get the `valueRef.current.some is not a function` error when opening the input options
3. If I deselect everything, I will get the `Cannot read property 'toString' of null` error in `App.js`.

What is the correct way to load initial values to the select in this case?

Here is my codesandbox for reference:

[image: Edit distracted-fast-zl3dk]